# factory contract storage patterns

Tags: solidity

i'm new to solidity and trying to understand the better storage option for the factory contract. i want:

1. to be able to get all deployed contracts.
2. to be able to get all deployed contracts by creator

The option i see is to create an array to track all contracts and mapping to reference the creators, ex:

```
contract CampaignFactory {

    Campaign[] campaigns;
    mapping(address => Campaign[]) campaignsByOwner;

    function createCampaign(uint min_contrib) public {
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(min_contrib, msg.sender);
        campaignsByOwner[msg.sender].push(newCampaign);
        campaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }

    function getAllCampaigns() public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        return campaigns;
    }

    function getCampaignByAddress(address creator) public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        return campaignsByOwner[creator];
    }
}
```

alternatively, i could use a struct like:

```
struct CampaignDeployed() {
    address creator;
    address[] campaigns;
}
```

but in that case as i understand, to get a campaigns by owner i will have to iterate over all in `for` cycle, which is something possibly too expensive (?).

So, the questions is, what is the typical approach to tackle such problem? does the solution with `array` + `mapping` acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is good, but if the arrays get too big, you may not be able to return them all at once. Different nodes impose different limits, but there's often a timeout and a maximum allowed payload on calls to view functions.

You may be interested in pagination (specifically the "paging through an array" section): https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/04/20/storage-patterns-pagination/.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [simple storage patterns in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity). It talks about pros/cons using different combinations of data structures.

In may opinion, it depends on your needs. 
For example, can the need *"to be able to get all deployed contracts"* be solved by calling externally `getCampaignByAddress()` multiple times? It would involve multiple smart contract calls and the knowledge about all addresses with at least a campaign, but may save your support array data struct.

I struggled a lot about this issue before, hope my contribution helps.

Comment: it is possible to get all the data by calling `getCampaignByAddress()` theoretically, but practically there will be to much constraints to use it - all the creator addresses not always available when this call need to be made for example. Thanks for list, seen that.